Is it possible to approve/reject multiple records at once via LWC, Flow or standard Salesforce configurations?
Scenario: I have an approver who spends the day approving records, but due to the high number of approvals, he loses a lot of time opening each opportunity to be approved.
I'm looking for a way to create something to make his life easier.

I think we need a bit more information as to what he needs to see in order to approve a record. Could the fields all fit in a listview?
